# Hide items when the countdown timer is 02:30

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, jquery-events

I have a code problem I don't know how to hide items when my timer reaches 02:30. The timer also resets when it reaches 0, and I want items to be displayed until the timer ticks 02:30. Can anyone help me with the code? This divs need to be hidden when the timer is 02:30

Timer Ticks from 03:00 to 0 and reset.

When I refresh the page timer is restarted how can fix that? How can I do session, cookie, or localStorage for time to not reset when the page is reloaded? Can somebody help me with that?

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function($) {
  var threeMinutes = 60 * 3,
    display = $('#timer');
  startTimer(threeMinutes, display);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="timer" class="text-center" style="margin-top:100px;">03:00</h1>
<div class="alert alert-info">File List</div>
<div class="alert alert-info">File List</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide items when the timer reaches 2:30:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

    $(".alert").toggle(timer >= 150)
    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function($) {
  var threeMinutes = 60 * 3,
    display = $('#timer');
  startTimer(threeMinutes, display);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="timer" class="text-center" style="margin-top:100px;">03:00</h1>
<div class="alert alert-info">File List</div>
<div class="alert alert-info">File List</div>
```

Version with localStorage - this version stops the timer when not visible

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Persist timer</title>
  <style>
    .alert {
      display: none
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration,
        minutes, seconds;
      setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        $(".alert").toggle(timer >= 150); // show when 2:30
        if (--timer < 0) {
          timer = duration;
        }
        localStorage.setItem("timer", timer);

      }, 1000);
    }

    $(function() {
      const display = $('#timer');
      let threeMinutes = localStorage.getItem("timer"); // timer will continue from where it stopped but without elapsing while not running
      threeMinutes = threeMinutes ? +threeMinutes : 60 * 3
      startTimer(threeMinutes, display);
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="timer" class="text-center" style="margin-top:100px;"></h1>
  <div class="alert alert-info">File List</div>
  <div class="alert alert-info">File List</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't know javascript so well, yes I mean that.

Comment: When I refresh the page timer is restarted how can fix that? How can I do session, cookie, or localStorage for time to not reset when the page is reloaded?

Comment: I update my question can you please help me with that?

Comment: `let time = localStorage.getItem("timer"); if (!time)time=60*3;` ... and then after the if (—timer) {...} you add `localStorage.setItem("timer",timer)` or you give a time stamp instead and test against expiry

Comment: can you please edit your code here so I can see properly?

Comment: Later. I am not near a computer

Comment: please do not forget I need this one

Comment: I don't know javascript so well that's why  i need your help to edit your code for me to see it

Comment: https://plungjan.name/SO/persisttimer.html - I added this version. Let me know if you need the timer to keep running even when not loaded into the browser

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** here's an updated fiddle which includes an option to auto reset the timer after reaching 0: https://jsfiddle.net/gawpsoy8/1/

this might be more than you asked for, but this sort of logic is best broken up into a few parts, meaning a few functions and a few variables. that said, it's good practice to generally limit the amount of functions and variables you introduce into the global scope of the project and so in this case it would be smart to try and encapsulate those. there are a few options, one approach might be to create a JavaScript `class` which will encapsolate all the logic in an organized fashion and only introduce a single name into the global namespace (that of the class itself). for example:

```js
class Timer {
    constructor (opts) {
    this.duration = opts.duration
    this.ele = document.querySelector(opts.element)
    this.hideAt = opts.hideAt
    this.time = 0
    this.timer = null
  }
  
  startTimer () {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
    this.time = this.duration
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.update(), 1000)
  }
  
  milliToMins (millis) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000)
    const seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0)
    return minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds
  }
  
  update () {
    this.time -= 1000
    this.ele.textContent = this.milliToMins(this.time)
    if (this.time === this.hideAt) this.ele.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

this has the added benefit of being a bit more customizable as you can easily change the element that will display the timer, the starting duration and the time at which to hide that element, all by simply updating the "options" you pass to the timer when you "instantiate it", for example:

```js
const myTimer = new Timer({
  element: '#timer',
  duration: 3 * 60 * 1000,
  hideAt: 2.5 * 60 * 1000
})
```

after instantiating it you can start the timer by calling:

```js
myTimer.startTimer()
```

also, worth noting you don't really need jQuery for this (which is why I wrote it in plain JavaScript).

here's the example running in a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gawpsoy8/